# Slash command that updates Slack bot code in Python?

Tags: python, slack-commands

I'm trying to write a Slack bot in Python. One of the functionalities I'm looking for is a way to toggle on/off a daily report message using a slash command, or some other kind of interactive message system in a Slack DM or channel with the bot.

Right now I have a boolean variable, `post` which is set to `True`. The idea is that when a user sends a slash command message, say `/post-off` to the Slack bot, `post` will be set to `False`. I'm developing in Socket Mode, so what this looks like is:

```
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler

slack_client = WebClient(token=SLACK_TOKEN)
handler = SocketModeHandler(app, SLACK_APP_TOKEN)
handler.start()

post = True

if post:
     slack_client.chat_postMessage(channel=CHANNEL, text=TEXT)
```

However, even without trying to insert code changing `post` (which I plan on doing via a slash command, thus me inserting the handler code), my message isn't posting to the channel. When I comment out the two lines of handler code, though, the message sends. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I'm also not sure how to manipulate the variable value with my slash command.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/api-docs/slack_bolt/adapter/socket_mode/base_handler.html#slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode.base_handler.BaseSocketModeHandler.start) of the .start() method, this is a blocking operation. If you don't want this to happen, use connect instead.

"Establishes a new connection and then blocks the current thread to prevent the termination of this process. If you don't want to block the current thread, use #connect() method instead."

Comment: The issue with `connect()` is that when the file finishes executing the process stops and the bot goes offline/stops listening--can you think of any ways around this?

Comment: At some point in the program, you'll need to enter some sort of loop to keep the process active. What is the source that would trigger a post (if post is True)? How/when are you checking the source?